# How to set environment variables in VSCode when running Flask app?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a Python Flask app and have lots of environment variables that I need to set when running my app. I normally run my app like so...

```
python3 -m app.py
```

I would like it so that I can set all the environment variables my app needs so that I do not need to export each time I reopen my terminal. It would be nice if it could be workspace-specific or project-specific.

I know other editors like Pycharm can do similar things and was wondering how to do this in VS Code?

Comment: **SOLUTION!** Take a look here stackoverflow.com/a/70748562/3223785 .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Flask apps, you can create a *launch.json* configuration that will [run your Flask app using VS Code's debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_run-the-app-in-the-debugger). VS Code's *launch.json* supports a number of  options, including the setting of environment variables that your Flask app needs.

Start with installing the [Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), to add support for "*debugging of a number of types of Python applications*, which [includes Flask](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-specific-app-types). Then, follow the [Flask Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) from the VS Code docs.

Basically, you'll need to create a *launch.json* file in your workspace's *.vscode* folder.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "run-flask-app",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "/path/to/app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "0",
                "AAA": "value of AAA env var",
                "BBB": "value of BBB env var",
                "CCC": "value of CCC env var"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
    ]
}
```

The `env` portion is where you set all the environment variables. By default, it includes the required `FLASK_*`-related variables because it uses the [flask command line tool](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#command-line-interface) for running apps.

Here, as an example, I've also set custom `AAA` and `BBB` and `CCC` vars. You can access that from code as normal env vars:

```
@app.route('/test')
def root():
    aaa = os.environ.get("AAA")
    bbb = os.environ.get("BBB")
    ccc = os.environ.get("CCC")
    print(f'{aaa}, {bbb}, {ccc}')
    return f'{aaa}, {bbb}, {ccc}'
```

Then run it from the Debug panel:

[image: run the code]

Just hit the play button and you should be able to see the `print`ed env values from the Terminal panel or from the browser after accessing the `/test` endpoint. (If you have multiple terminals, it should appear under the *Python Debug Console*).

[image: result]

Lastly, by saving the *.vscode/launch.json* file under the workspace folder, then it's workspace-specific, and it will only affect the runtime environment used to launch your Flask app.

Comment: It seems the "env": {...}, statement needs to appear near the top of the "configurations" section to take effect.

Comment: @JohnMark Hmmm... I cannot reproduce your issue. The order should *not* matter here because it's in JSON format *where the order does not matter* (unless Microsoft's code for parsing a JSON object is dumb enough to consider order). [I tried re-arranging the config keys and it still works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nTqc.png). Even the [Flask debugging docs on VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_flask-debugging) does not mention anything about order.

Comment: @JohnMark If the order does indeed matter on your env (I really can't reproduce it), then I would say that's a bug on VS Code, and if you can manage a [mcve], then [report it to the VS Code team](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: A file is required? How about passing credentials via en vars then?

Comment: @mirekphd I don't understand your question. The question was about running a Flask app _in VS Code_ and being able to pass env vars at the same time. My answer is about doing that using VS Code's launch.json, which allows you to run your app through VS Code's debugger. There may be other ways, that doesn't need to use launch.json or other files, but I don't know about them because that's not what my answer is about. The value of the env vars is also irrelevant, whether they are simple strings or credentials. I suggest re-reading both question and answer, or posting a separate question.

Comment: Nothing wrong in your posted answer. It's just a rant on another "gotcha" in this MSFT IDE. Just like VS Code (code) extensions installer is not working in a non-interactive mode, so do env vars fail to represent reality of a production system in this IDE (unlike other IDEs: Jupyter, RStudio, etc. where it just works fine). Linux system CLI i.e. shell not passing all env vars to the app started later in that shell is a highly unrealistic test environment, We cannot use VSC for testing containerized apps (REST APIs in general and Flask apps in particular) for that very reason...

Comment: To be more constructive I channeled the above rant into a feature request in `code-server` issue tracker: https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/5985